# HTML table with a floating header row in a Heredoc

Tags: jquery, html, header, floating, heredoc

I have been tasked with taking over a project where an interface tool is being developed for a Postgre SQL database.

What I am trying to do is have a locked / floating table header within a heredoc. The table rows are being acquired from the database and returned to the main display heredoc and displayed without any issues.

However, I have not been table header to float as a user scrolls through the results.  I know the floating header code is functional as I have been able to get it to work in a separate "project" when it is not contained within a heredoc.

PHP heredoc snippet:

```
<div>
    (menu bar setup)
</div>
$submenu
<div id="ContentBody">
    $content
</div>
```

$content houses the returning table data.

The original setup of table to be returned:

`$out = '<div id="divExt">'.
            '<table name="myTable" id="theTable">'.$th.$out.'</table>'.
        '</div>';
return $out;`

Updated setup  to have a floating table header:

`$out = '<div id="divExt">'.
            '<table name="myTable" id="theTable">'.$th.$out.'</table>'.
        '</div>'.

        '<script>'.
            'var $table = $(".myTable");'.
            '$table.floatThead ({scrollContainer: function ($table) {return $table.closest("wrapper");} });'.
            '$( document ).ready(function() {alert("Should float;");});'.
        '</script>';
return $out;`

The alert was put in there as a test to see if the JS would work in there at all.  The alert fires, but the table header does not float.

"jquery.min.js" and "jquery.floatThead.js" have been placed on the server and are within the head section of the heredoc, and to the best of my knowledge they are being access properly.

Any ideas / input / guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`var $table = $(".myTable");` will select an element with class `myTable` not its **name**!

need to change your html to add a class, or use the name selector.